# how to fix installing restkit ios error?

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I got the following problem while installing the restkit on xcode 4.5 ,

**clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/omar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYApplication-bdmknibmydzygicvcnkavqemwxic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit/RestKit'**

i read the trouble shooting manual but it does not fix my issue  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installation-Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by downloading the restkit files as in the documentation,

then from terminal try to update the git repo  of the restkit

- open the terminal and go to your project folder.
- find the restkit folder inside the project.
- type: **git pull**.
- now the trunk of the restkit will be updated again and load all changed or newly added files.

I hope this will fix any one faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you added both Restkit.Framework and libRestKit.a.
Choose one: libRestKit.a is for iOS, the other for Max OS X